# Fill inside a rectangle with a pattern Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Using the following code in delphi-firemonkey, it is easy to fill a rectangle with a solid or gradient color, but I cannot figure out how to fill it with a pattern like dots or slant dashes.

```
FillRect(RectF(a,b, c,d), 70, tbrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid,TAlphaColorRec.gray));
```

appreciate the help.

Comment: I suspect you didn't read the description of the "design-patterns" tag. Anyhow: This seems to be about Firemonkey (FMX), is that right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand yes it is

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I just read it twice and did not get it :(

Comment: See https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBrush.Bitmap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a bitmap to provide the "dots and slants" or any figure to use as the pattern. In this case you define `TBrushKind.Bitmap` when you create the brush.

Here is an example that keeps the pattern brush as part of the form. The comments explain the details.

```
  private
    Brush: TBrush;
    BrushBmp: TBrushBitmap;

procedure TForm48.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BrushBmp := TBrushBitmap.Create;
  // Load bitmap to be used as brush
  BrushBmp.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('C:\tmp\BrushA.bmp');
  // Create the brush of proper TBrushKind
  Brush := TBrush.Create(TBrushKind.Bitmap, TAlphaColorRec.Aqua);
  // Assign the bitmap to the brush
  Brush.Bitmap := BrushBmp;
end;

procedure TForm48.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Brush.Free;
end;

procedure TForm48.Rectangle1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRectF);
begin
  // use the bitmap brush
  Canvas.FillRect(ARect, 0.0, 0.0, AllCorners, 1.0, Brush, TCornerType.Bevel);
end;
```

The bitmap:

[image]

And when used as a fill:

[image]

Comment: +1, but in real code you would of course protect your resources so that the `TBrushBitmap` object isn't leaked if the `LoadFromFile` fails.